# The meat mince is rough

Tags: word-usage, image-identification, food

> The meat mince is rough.

(When the grinder used is larger size or didn't grinde twice time.)

What word do we use if the meat is a bit big and not grinde well.

[image]

[image]

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I would say the meat is *coarsely* ground.

Generally you can use *coarsely* or *finely* ground/chopped/minced etc.